# Basic authentication in mule has no effect using the MEL expression

Tags: mule

Basic authentication in mule has no effect using the MEL expression. 
How do you make the user name and password dynamic?

[image]

Comment: Username and password can be dynamic since Mule 3.7.0 (https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8573). Can you share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a bug open in this similar case where flow variables are used as dynamically in HTTP config:- https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8895

Need to check which Mule version you are using... It should work from **Mule version 3.7+**

**Alternately** you can try the following example :-

```
   <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration2" host="0.0.0.0" port="8089" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

     <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="#[flowVars['urlHost']]" port="#[flowVars['urlHostPort']]" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>

     <flow name="muleclientFlow">
         <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration2" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
         <set-payload value="gdfgdfgdgsd" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         <set-variable variableName="urlHost" value="localhost" doc:name="Variable"/>
         <set-variable variableName="urlHostPort" value="8081" doc:name="Variable"/>

         <set-variable variableName="urlHostUser" value="anon" doc:name="Variable"/>
         <set-variable variableName="urlHostPassword" value="anon" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="basic_credentials" value="#[flowVars.urlHostUser+':'+flowVars.urlHostPassword]" doc:name="Variable"/>

         <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
              <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="#['Basic ' + org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(flowVars.basic_credentials.getBytes())]"/>
           </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
         <logger message="Success !!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     </flow>
```

Here you can see that I have used another flow variable basic_credentials which combines both the variables `#[flowVars.urlHostUser+':'+flowVars.urlHostPassword]` :-

```
<set-variable variableName="basic_credentials" value="#[flowVars.urlHostUser+':'+flowVars.urlHostPassword]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

and finally passing it in HTTP request config as :-

```
 <http:request-builder>
        <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="#['Basic ' + org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(flowVars.basic_credentials.getBytes())]"/>
   </http:request-builder>
```

ref:- https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/34854/dynamically-set-username-and-password-http-request.html